# How to request "Marketing user" permission in my Salesforce App?

Tags: permissions, app

I'm creating an app and the user installing the package must have "Marketing User" permissions (must be able to **create/update/destroy campaigns**).

Are there any requirement I can set on my App? I was looking for it but the only I found was "Full Access" which is a bit too much from my point of view.

Comment: Are you creating/updating/destroying campaigns while installation ?

Comment: No, I'm creating/updating/destroying "all time" with bulk API, when I create some stuff on my software, I send it to salesforce, so it doesn't happen only during installation, but whenever software is used.

Comment: Ok. so installation wont fail if this permission is unchecked. Its the future usage of the application that may fail if this permission is not present. right?

Answer (score 0):

Go to setup -> Users -> your user

You will see a check box "Marketing User"

Check it and you should be all set.